# WindowsBuilder is not working on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, swt, windowbuilder

This is Anas here and I just wonder if one can share his though about windowsbuilder on eclipse. I installed it from help link through selecting SWT, GWT other plugins and all gone well but after a restart those plugins are not working. Precisely, Eclipse IDE is showing those links enabled but it takes me to interface asking to install some additional toolkits, again when I proceed, I met a repository not found error.

Hunting over web, I have tried -clean and checked my port address. Thanks for your comment!!

Comment: Are the Eclipse webtools installed? I always suggest to use the "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" as base for your GWT IDE because this package inludes everything needed by the GPE/WindowBuilder.

Comment: Which one is it? GWT or SWT?

Comment: @brano88, Steffen : Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Baz: Neither GWT nor SWT is working but as I said link is there and enabled.

Comment: I am little skeptical if I am getting the problem correctly or not but the log information is here.

Unhandled event loop exception:
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)... more

Answer (score 0):

```
Well Anas,
I understood your problem so follow these simple steps to overcome this solutions
First install the Indigo[3.7.2] version  Eclipse from this link:
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

And then go to eclipse--->Help---->InstallNewSoftware and paste the below link>

WindowBuilder[1.6] Pro Update Site - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7

And select WindowBuilder Specific Checkboxes and proceed accordingly.
After that if you want to do a simple example of using windowBuider 
just go through this link it might be helpful for you in this regard:
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/NewComponentsTutorial.pdf
In case still you are facing issues feel free to reach me SUNIL
```

Comment: Hi Sunil, thanks for your descriptive reply and i am going to try this but let me extend my question as this issue persist. Is Juno is not a stable version and what could be the possible problem I am experiencing with it? I mean neither GWT, SWT, nor other plugins are working while link is enabled! I appreciate your reply any ways.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question so I can give proper response.And I don't think there is no problem with Juno version.It just need to install completely.

Comment: I was intended to ask once view that why plugins not working with Juno. Further with thanks as now I am learning with Indigo following your steps! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check over here for available WindowsBuilder versions:

- https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php

Take a link, and pass it on Eclipse IDE's feature installer, which takes the URI. Aim for the version of the builder which is supported by that IDE version.

If you take the latest version of WindowsBuilder, it does not mean that the specific IDE does support it.

Best regards